# Threads not able to perform cleanup using CancellationToken

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a windows service that spawns some threads and I'm trying to make sure they shut down properly.

The service is defined as

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Started");
        logger.Info("Service Starting");

        docProcessors = new DocProcessor[NumberOfThreads];
        workerThreads = new Thread[NumberOfThreads];
        logger.Debug($"Service Starting {NumberOfThreads} Threads");
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfThreads; i++)
        {
            logger.Debug($"Service thread {i+1} starting");
            docProcessors[i] = new DocProcessor(i+1,eventLog1);
            bool b = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(docProcessors[i].StartProcess), cts.Token);
            logger.Debug($"Service thread {i+1} started");
        }
        logger.Info("Service Started");

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        logger.Info("Service Stopping");
        cts.Cancel();
        cts.Dispose();
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Stopped");
        logger.Info("Service Stopped");
    }
```

And the worker like so (minus the actual work...)

```
    public void StartProcess(object obj)
    {
        token = (CancellationToken)obj;

        token.Register(() =>
        {
            logger.Debug($"Thread {ThreadNumber} Cancel Requested ");
            isCancelled = true;
        });


        noticeLogger.Info($"StartProcess {threadNumber}");
        logger.Info($"StartProcess {threadNumber}");
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        while (KeepRunning())
        {


            if (KeepRunning())
            {
                int seconds = 30;                   
                logger.Trace($"{threadNumber} sleeping {seconds} seconds");
                Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds));
            }
        }

        logger.Info($"DocProcessor thread {ThreadNumber} complete");
        noticeLogger.Info($"DocProcessor thread {ThreadNumber} complete");

    }
```

When I stop the service, I typically see something like

```
2019-03-21 10:13:55.0403 INFO Service Stopping
2019-03-21 10:13:55.0403 DEBUG Thread 2 Cancel Requested
2019-03-21 10:13:55.0403 DEBUG Thread 1 Cancel Requested
2019-03-21 10:13:55.0403 INFO Service Stopped
```

But I never see anything like 
"DocProcessor thread 1 complete"
which would mean the StartProcess method never runs to completion, I presume.

Additionally, and probably most importantly, if there is actually work happening it just stops in the middle.

I'm assuming I'm doing something fundamentally incorrect.

Comment: I have no idea what `KeepRunning` does but it seems that if *anything* is interacting with the cancellation token (other than looking) it must be in there? But it's not passed the token?

Comment: Keep running just pays attention to the cancellation state and an error threshold.

        private bool KeepRunning()
        {
            return WithinErrorThreshold() && !isCancelled;
        }

Comment: You need to wait for some kind of a signal in the `OnStop` method. The simplest way is to call `Join` on the worker thread(s) or something like `WaitHandle.WaitAll`.

Comment: After `cts.Cancel()`, you need to wait for the cancel request to be honored by the ThreadPool threads

Comment: Thanks @Luaan I passed some ManualResetEvent to my workers and waited on those and it seems to work.